# how to use sweetalert plugin in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert

so i have here my `sweetalert2` plugin and im trying to used it on my success function on my ajax.. here is my code..

```
        $.ajax({
            url:'../ajax/checklogin.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'JSON',
            data:$('form').serialize(),   
            success: function(result){

                if(result){
                   swal('Success', 'Login Successfully.!', 'success');
       $.post("../pages/login.php",{ users_id: parseInt(result.users_id)}).done(window.location.href='../pages/dashboard.php');
                }else{
                     swal("Error", "Incorrect Credentials.!", "error");
                }

             },
             error: function(status){
                        console.log(status.responseText);
             }
        });
```

my problem is i dont know how to use the success button on the `swal` cuz when i tried running it what happen is it just call the success return. what i wanted to make is the first the swal will show up then after clicking the success button or much better if to show that the user successfully logged in then closed the `swal` and run the `$.post()` how can i possibly do that??..  i tried using base on the link of sweetalert but im getting nowhere..